# Batch Convert Sony raw ".ARW" image files to .jpg with raw image settings on the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, imagemagick, lightroom, sips

I am looking to convert 15 Million 12.8 mb Sony .ARW files to .jpg

I have figured out how to do it using sips on the Command line BUT what I need is to make adjustments to the raw image settings: Contrast, Highlights, Blacks, Saturation, Vibrance, and most importantly Dehaze.  I would be applying the same settings to every single photo.

It seems like ImageMagick should work if I can make adjustments for how to incorporate Dehaze but I can't seem to get ImageMagick to work.

I have done benchmark testing comparing Lightroom Classic / Photoshop / Bridge / RAW Power / and a few other programs.  Raw Power is fastest by far (on a M1 Mac Mini 16GB Ram) but Raw Power doesn't allow me to process multiple folders at once.

I do a lot of scripting / actions with photoshop - but in this case photoshop is by far the slowest option.  I believe this is because it opens each photo.

Answer (score 1):

That's 200TB of input images, without even allowing any storage space for output images. It's also 173 solid days of 24 hr/day processing, assuming you can do 1 image per second - which I doubt.

You may want to speak to Fred Weinhaus @fmw42 about his [Retinex](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/retinex/index.php) script (search for *"hazy"* on that page), which does a rather wonderful job of haze removal. Your project sounds distinctly commercial.

[image]

© Fred Weinhaus - [Fred's ImageMagick scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php)

If/when you get a script that does what you want, I would suggest using **GNU Parallel** to get decent performance. I would also think you may want to consider porting, or having ported, Fred's algorithm to C++ or Python to run with **OpenCV** rather than **ImageMagick**.

So, say you have a 24-core MacPro, and a `bash` script called `ProcessOne` that takes the name of a Sony `ARW` image as parameter, you could run:

```
find . -iname \*.arw -print0 | parallel --progress -0 ProcessOne {}
```

and that will recurse in the current directory finding all Sony `ARW` files and passing them into **GNU Parallel**, which will then keep all 24-cores busy until the whole lot are done. You can specify fewer, or more jobs in parallel with, say, `parallel -j 8 ...`

**Note 1**: You *could* also list the names of additional servers in your network and it will spread the load across them too. **GNU Parallel** is capable of transferring the images to remote servers along with the jobs, but I'd have to question whether it makes sense to do that for this task - you'd probably want to put a subset of the images on each server with its own local disk I/O and run the servers independently yourself rather than distributing from a single point globally.

**Note 2**: You will want your disks well configured to handle multiple, parallel I/O streams.

**Note 3**: If you do write a script to process an image, write it so that it accepts **multiple** filenames as parameters, then you can run `parallel -X` and it will pass as many filenames as your `sysctl` parameter `kern.argmax` allows. That way you won't need a whole `bash` or OpenCV C/C++ process per image.

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, I hope you don't mind my including a screen-grab from your website. If you do, please feel free to edit and remove it, or tell me and I will remove immediately.

Comment: That is OK. But retinex is very slow. Perhaps one of my other scripts would be better such as my space or autotone2 or adaptivegamma scripts.

Comment: My scripts are at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick